# Reducibility of $f(x)^{2^n}+1$ and $f(x)^{2^n}+g(x)^{2^n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, factorization

Related to generalized Fermat numbers.

Let $f(x),g(x)$ be coprime polynomials with integer coefficients.

Assume that if $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ are of the form $h(x)^k$ then $k$ is power
of two.

> Q1 Is it possible for infinitely many $n$,$f(x)^{2^n}+g(x)^{2^n}$ to be reducible?

> Q2 Is it possible for infinitely many  $n$,$f(x)^{2^n}+1$ to be reducible?

---

Added: To avoid constant factors suggested by `Maciej Ulas`,
I want reducibility over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and don't count constant factors.

Comment: I take it "reducible" means "reducible over the integers".

Comment: If $f(x)=2f_{1}(x)+1, g(x)=2g_{1}(x)+1$, where $f_{1}, g_{1}$ are given non-zero polynomials, then the polynomials $f(x)^{2^{n}}+g^{2^{n}}, f(x)^{2^{n}}+1$ as divisible by 2, are reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @MaciejUlas Thanks for the counterexample. I edited, wanting reducibility over Q[x] and don't count constant factors.